# 2D array using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic, multidimensional-array, 2d

I am attempting to read a file with some random  names in the format "ADAM","MARK","JESSIE" .....

I have some constraints, the file should be read in a function but should be accessible form the main function with no global variables.
The file size and the no of names in the file are not known.
This is what I have done till now. I have some difficulty with dynamic 2d array as I have not used them much.

```
/* Function to read from the file */
int read_names(FILE *input, char ***names, int *name_count)
{
    int f1,size,count,i,j=0;
    char **name_array,*text,pos=0;
    /* get the file size */
    f1=open("names.txt",O_RDONLY);
    size=lseek(f1,0,SEEK_END);
    close(f1);
    /* Reading all the characters of the file into memory */
    //Since file size is known we can use block transfer
    text=(char *) malloc(size * sizeof(char) );
    fscanf(input,"%s",text);

    /* Finding the no of names in the file */
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(text[i]==',')
            count++;
    }
    printf("No. of names determined\n");

    /* Assigning the Name count to the pointer */
    name_count=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *name_count=count;


    name_array=(char **) malloc(count * sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        name_array[i]=(char*) malloc(10 *sizeof(char ));
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(text[i]!='"')
            if(text[i]==',')
            {
                **name_array[pos][j]='\0'; //error here
                pos++;
                j=0;
            }
            else
                name_array[pos][j++]=text[i];
    }
    printf("Names Counted\n");
    printf("Total no of names: %d\n",*name_count);
    names=(char ***) malloc(sizeof(char **);
    names=&name_array;
    return 1;
}

/* Main Function */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    char ***names;
    int *name_count;
    int status;
    // Opening the file
    fp = fopen("names.txt","r");
    // Now read from file
    status = read_names(fp,names,name_count);
    printf("From Main\n");
    fclose(fp);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I use WxDev and am getting an error "invalid type argument of `unary *' when I try to assign the null character.

Any pointers on how to do this?

Comment: You might want to try formatting your code, as it's hard for others to read in its present form.

Comment: The fact that you open 'names.txt' twice should indicate to you there is some kind of problem.

Comment: what is the use of char*** name in the function read_names?

Comment: @Paul: I will improve the comments...
@sje397: hmmm... din really think about it since i did not get a warning or error and since I am opening them as read only i think i did not get any error.
@Manoj R: I have edited the code now to indicate the use of the triple pointer. I thought I could access this 2-d array in the main function this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            **name_array[pos][j]='\0'; \\error here
```

I see that `name_array` is declared as

```
char **name_array
```

Problem is that

`**name_array[pos][j]` tries to dereference (twice!!) a character

```
**   (name_array[pos]) [j];    /* name_array[pos] is of type (char*) */
** ( (name_array[pos]) [j] );  /* name_array[pos][j] is of type (char) */
```

You cannot dereference a character.

**Suggestion: simplify your code.**
*When code doesn't "behave", it usually is not because it is too simple* ;)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will do more reading on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at this expression from the line generating the error and think about what it's doing:

```
**name_array[pos][j]
```

Remembering that brackets have higher [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) than unary *, this is equivalent to `*(*((name_array[pos])[j]))`, which is 2 subscripts followed by 2 dereferences. That's a total of 4 dereferences, since `foo[i]` is equivalent to `*(foo+i)`. The declared type of `name_array` is `char **`, which means you can only dereference it twice. Think of the type declaration `char **name_array` as meaning that `**name_array` has type `char`, since that's the basis for type declaration syntax (see the [History of C](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html), "Embryonic C").

### Off topic

Another issue arises on the line:

```
name_array[i]=(char*) malloc(sizeof(char ));
```

Here, you're only allocating enough space for a single character in each element of `name_array`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake in the deferences and the memory allocation. I will do more reading on the topic.

Answer (score -1):

This might seem pedantic, but it is important.  You aren't using a 2D array.  In fact, you don't create **ANY** arrays in your code.

One of the important things to understand is that arrays "decay" into pointers.

[link text](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html)

> Much of the confusion surrounding arrays and pointers in C can be traced to a misunderstanding of this statement. Saying that arrays and pointers are `equivalent'' means neither that they are identical nor even interchangeable. What it means is that array and pointer arithmetic is defined such that a pointer can be conveniently used to access an array or to simulate an array. In other words, as Wayne Throop has put it, it's`pointer arithmetic and array indexing [that] are equivalent in C, pointers and arrays are different.'')